# How to pass uint8_t from python to C?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, swig

I have methods in C below, is there a way to convert python int into uint8_t?

I have tried ctypes.c_uint8(...), numpy.uint8(...), and struct.pack('B', ...), all of them throw argument 1 of type 'uint8_t'

The python code is generated via swig, python part looks like

```
def hello(value):
    return _swigdemo.hello(value)
hello = _swigdemo.hello

def hello2(value):
    return _swigdemo.hello2(value):
hello2 = _swigdemo.hello2
```

C code

```
uint8_t hello(uint8_t value)
{
    return value;
}

uint8_t * hello2(uint8_t *value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Calling the method below

```
import swigdemo
import numpy
import ctypes
import struct

temp = ctypes.c_uint8(5) // or numpy.uint8(5) or struct.pack('B', 5)
swigdemo.hello(temp);
```

Will throw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'hello', argument 1 of type 'uint8_t'
```

Comment: Please show us some Python code, preferably a [mcve], that illustrates this error. Don't forget to include the full Traceback of the error.

Comment: The python code is generated via swig, will not be able to post the source. But I will update the post.

Comment: Apologies, updated the post with traceback and how did I call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG doesn't know what the `uint8_t` type is.  You can add `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` to the SWIG interface file to let it know.  Here's a self-contained example. Note: `%inline` declares both source code and tells SWIG to wrap it.

```
%module x

%inline %{
    typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

    uint8_t hello(uint8_t value)
    {
        return value;
    }
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.hello(5)
5
>>> x.hello(255)
255
>>> x.hello(256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: in method 'hello', argument 1 of type 'uint8_t'
```